# Extracting NDVI values from hdr file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, modis, envi

I have a dataset of hdr files of MYD13A2 MODIS product including 4 bands NDVI, EVI, quality, and reliability.
I want to extract the NDVI values for a group of points; I have the geographic coordinate of each point (lon, lat) using ArcMap.

How can I do it?

Comment: don't you mean hdf files ? Are you able to open your file in ArcGIS ?

Comment: hdr files are generated by ENVI in fact I performed a mosaicking operation on my modis tiles to get a complete image of the study area using ENVI. And I'm not able to open these files on ArcMap that's the problem

Comment: To ask about doing this in any other software please use a separate question and specify the particular software you wish to ask about.

Answer (score 1):

hdr is the header of ENVI files, you should have an associated file without extension (and with the same name as the hdr file). In order to open this file in ArcMap, try addinf the ".dat" extension to the file without extension. Then you can use "extract multi-value to point" from the spatial analyst toolbox in order to get the NDVI values for each point.

Comment: Thanks for your response but even when I added ".dat" extension to the file without extension I couldn't open it in ArcMap